# Segmented circle with dynamic text inside hoverable segments

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

I am trying to create segmented circle diagram with borders, box shadows on segments and dynamic text baselines that follow the segment radius.

I've tried to create this using `html` and `css`, but I've not having much luck. Maybe `svg` or `canvas` might be a better solution but not sure how to approach this.

Here is what I have tried using `html` and `css`...

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.circle {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle__center {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
  left: calc(50% - 2px);
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
}

.layer1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.layer2 {
  background: black;
  height: 375px;
  width: 375px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 187.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 187.5px);
}

.layer2__wrapper {
  height: 370px;
  width: 370px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: calc(50% - 185px);
  left: calc(50% - 185px);
}

.layer3 {
  background: black;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 300;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 125px);
  left: calc(50% - 125px);
}

.layer3__wrapper {
  height: 245px;
  width: 245px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: calc(50% - 122.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 122.5px);
}

.layer4 {
  background: black;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 400;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 62.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 62.5px);
}

.layer4__wrapper {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: calc(50% - 60px);
  left: calc(50% - 60px);
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}

.item:hover {
  background: purple;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: skew(38.57142857deg, 6.428571429deg);
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: skew(-12.8571428deg, 57.85714286deg);
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(90deg) skew(25.71428571deg, 19.28571429deg);
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) skew(64.28571429deg, -19.28571429deg);
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) skew(12.85714286deg, 32.14285714deg);
}

.item:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(270deg) skew(51.42857143deg, -6.428571429deg);
}

.item:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(270deg) skew(0, 45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="layer1">
    <div class="layer1__item item"></div>
    <div class="layer1__item item"></div>
    <div class="layer1__item item"></div>
    <div class="layer1__item item"></div>
    <div class="layer1__item item"></div>
    <div class="layer1__item item"></div>
    <div class="layer1__item item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer2">
    <div class="layer2__wrapper">
      <div class="layer2__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer2__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer2__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer2__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer2__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer2__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer2__item item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer3">
    <div class="layer3__wrapper">
      <div class="layer3__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer3__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer3__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer3__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer3__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer3__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer3__item item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer4">
    <div class="layer4__wrapper">
      <div class="layer4__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer4__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer4__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer4__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer4__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer4__item item"></div>
      <div class="layer4__item item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle__center"></div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this better?

I need editable segment text and each segment to be hoverable. Is this possible?

Here is a screenshot example of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: circle]

Comment: I know about it. One time i have ask how to create other figure, and only answer what i have got its "learn canvas". Its not an answer, its, like 'i cant breathe" and some one say to you "learn how to breathe". Im try to ask peoples mb who knows how to solve it, some hints or something. I dont ask to do this, and i will just only copy paste it. I can draw this circle in Illustrator and just put it in my code like vector, but its not good

Comment: Seeing as you are a newb, I edited your question to try and elaborate the focus for possible ideas and maybe a solution. But only the gods can decide if your question will re-open.

Comment: Are you asking how to curve text around the arcs? -- I know like divide word to parts, but i need full editable wordm not like 1 billion of span tags.
You don't have any text in your HTML. -- cuz its outside of circle only

Comment: Are you reading latest edit? I may have overridden previous edit. Sorry @isherwood

Comment: You could re-edit the question and replace the word `live` to `dynamic`. Which is essentially editable.

Comment: This would be difficult to achieve with HTML. But relatively simple with SVG.  For someone familiar with SVG, this could be built by hand in a text editor.  But for other people, I would suggest that you download Inkscape and recreate the image. Then you can export it and include it in your page.